# Store the first n values of the sequence 3Un² + 2Un +1 in an array using one function

Tags: arrays, c, performance, sequence

This is the sequence I'm working with:

U<sub>n+1</sub> = 3U<sub>n</sub>² + 2U<sub>n</sub> + 1
U₀ = 1

The first idea I get is a recursive function with a stopping condition of `n != 0`.
The problem is I want to store the value of each term in an array in the same function so I can print it later on

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long *Sequence(int n, unsigned long long *T) {
    while (n != 0) {
        T[n--] = 3 * (*(Sequence(n - 1, T) + n - 1)) * (*(Sequence(n - 1, T) + n - 1)) +
                 2 * (*(Sequence(n - 1, T) + n - 1)) + 1;
    }
    *T = 1;
    return T;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter your sequence term : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    unsigned long long *T = (unsigned long long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long) * (n + 1));
    T = Sequence(n, T);
    //Printing values
    printf("[   ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        printf("%5llu ", *(T + i));
    printf("   ]");
    
    free(T);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `unsigned long long` due to the huge numbers obtained from the sequence.
In the output I enter the term, but the array doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see what your program is doing to try to find the problem? You compute many of the sequence elements redundantly. For example, T[0] is set to 1 for _every_ call of Sequence(), and T[1] is computed in _every_ call with n > 0... and since they all share the same memory array T, each computation just overwrites  the results that were already there with the same values again. Instead you could first set T[0] = 1, then compute T[1] based on T[0], then T[2] based on T[1] etc. You would not even need recursion.

Comment: Also note that you decrement n (with n--) and use the value of n in the same statement inside of the while loop. When I compile this with Visual Studio 2019 it works as intended, but actually C doesn't define whether the n - 1 in the arguments to the recursive Sequence() calls will use the already decremented value of n or the old value before decrementing. Same problem for the +n-1 behind the function calls. You should not use ++ or -- together with another expression about the same variable in a single statement to avoid such risks.

Comment: that function grows **very** quickly, you likely want some other way of representing it.  i.e. only the first 5 terms fit into a 64bit integer.  the function is positive, so maybe you could work with the log of it instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>                                                                             
    
unsigned long long* Sequence(int n){
    unsigned long long* T=(unsigned long long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long)*(n+1));
    if(T==NULL){
    printf("Problem while allocating memory ! ");
    exit(1);
    }
    T[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) T[i]=3*T[i-1]*T[i-1]+2*T[i-1]+1;
    return T;
    }

int main(){
    int n ;
    unsigned long long *T;
    printf("Enter your term : ");scanf("%d",&n);
    T=Sequence(n);
    printf("[   ");
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) printf("%5llu ",*(T+i));
    printf("   ]");
    free(T);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help , here is the solution !

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive function for this computation is highly inefficient: the time complexity is exponential.  You should instead compute the values, starting from U<sub>0</sub> and computing and storing the values iteratively in a loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long next_term(unsigned long long u) {
    return 3 * u * u + 2 * u + 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter your sequence term: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    unsigned long long *T = calloc(sizeof(*T) * (n + 1));
    T[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        T[i] = next_term(T[i - 1]);
    }

    // Printing values
    printf("[   ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        printf("%llu ", T[i]));
    printf("   ]\n");
    
    free(T);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I commented that values from the series get large very quickly, here's some code to output this series that demonstrates this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static double logaddexp(double x, double y) {
    // like log(exp(x) + exp(y)) but don't over/underflow
    if (x < y) {
        double t = x;
        x = y;
        y = t;
    }
    return x + log1p(exp(y - x));
}

int
main() {
    const double l2 = log(2), l3 = log(3);
    double u = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        u = logaddexp(logaddexp(l3 + u * 2, l2 + u), 0);
        const long nbits = lround(ceil(u / l2));
        if (nbits < 53) {
            // report the actual value where this can be done accurately
            printf("U[%i] = %lli\n", i, llround(exp(u)));
        } else {
            printf("U[%i] ~= exp(%.3f), %li bit int needed\n", i, u, nbits);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

giving

```
U[1] = 6
U[2] = 121
U[3] = 44166
U[4] = 5851995001
U[5] ~= exp(46.079), 67 bit int needed
U[6] ~= exp(93.256), 135 bit int needed
U[7] ~= exp(187.611), 271 bit int needed
U[8] ~= exp(376.320), 543 bit int needed
U[9] ~= exp(753.739), 1088 bit int needed
U[10] ~= exp(1508.576), 2177 bit int needed
```

i.e. as can be seen from the definition you need more than `2**(n+1)` bits to get to item `n` in the series using integer values.